# How to get column distinct values of multiple columns as array with corresponding column name?

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to get the distinct values of multiple columns as arrays. I have tried use the function `array_agg`

```
    Color  |  State     |  Item
=================================
    Red    |  New York  |  Balloon
    Pink   |  Virginia  |  Table
    Black  |  Utah      |  Table
```

I want a table as

```
    Column_name  | Options
===============================
    Color        | [Red,Pink,Black]
    State        | [New York,Virginia,Utah]
    Item         | [Balloon,Table]
```

I have tried this:

```
select (array_agg(distinct "Color"))  from sample_table
union 
select (array_agg(distinct "State")) from sample_table
union 
select (array_agg(distinct "Item")) from sample_table
union
```

I am stuck at how to get the corresponding column names..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add your column_names like this:

```
SELECT 'Color' AS column_name, array_agg(distinct "Color") AS options from sample_table
UNION
SELECT 'State' AS column_name, array_agg(distinct "State") AS options from sample_table
UNION
SELECT 'Item' AS column_name, array_agg(distinct "Item") AS options from sample_table
```

Working [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/399e6/4)

Comment: It says `must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: I have added a fiddle for the same and used same name as yours.